# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia nonfunctional with newer phones

Tags: javascript, android, video-streaming

I'm having trouble getting video feed through my new Huawei P10 phone.
Strangely, it works fine with my old Huawei P7.
It lags during ondurationchange (approx 15 seconds) and never gives actual video even though it returns canplay.
I know this problem exists also in iPhone 6s.
Has anyone had similar problems or solutions?

UPDATE! 6.mar.2018

The problem seems to be with the browser platform.
I installed Firefox on my mobile and the code worked fine with it (althoug it kept pestering about giving rights to use the camera at every reload even though it was on a https server).

So just to iterate, the problem seems to be limited to Chrome mobile version.

Any chance that implementing adapter.js polyfill could resolve the problem. I really don't know what I am doing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
// Older browsers might not implement mediaDevices at all, so we set an empty object first
function strt(){

if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices = {};
}

// Some browsers partially implement mediaDevices. We can't just assign an object
// with getUserMedia as it would overwrite existing properties.
// Here, we will just add the getUserMedia property if it's missing.
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraints) {

    // First get ahold of the legacy getUserMedia, if present
    var getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    // Some browsers just don't implement it - return a rejected promise with an error
    // to keep a consistent interface
    if (!getUserMedia) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
    }

    // Otherwise, wrap the call to the old navigator.getUserMedia with a Promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
    });
  }
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: true })
.then(function(stream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  // Older browsers may not have srcObject
  if ("srcObject" in video) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
  } else {
    // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  }
  video.onloadstart = function(e) {
    alert("loadstart");
  };
  video.ondurationchange = function(e) {
    alert("ondurationchange");
  };
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    alert("meta");
    video.play();
  };
  video.onloadeddata = function(e) {
    alert("onloadeddata");
  };
  video.oncanplay = function(e) {
    alert("oncanplay");
  };
})
.catch(function(err) {
  alert(err.name + ": " + err.message);
  console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="strt()">
<video></video>
</body>
</html>
```